# Region finding based on VTK polylines

Tags: python, vtk, raytracing

I have the following domain that is made up of VTK poly lines -- each line starts and ends at a 'x', may have many points, and is assigned a left and right flag to denote the region on the left and right of that line, determined if you we walking down the line from start to end.

[image: the domain of interest]

For any random point `rp` in the domain, I need to work out which region it is in.

So far, I have tried:

- Calculating the nearest vtk point to `rp`, finding the curve to which it belongs and then calculating if `rp` is on the left or right of the curve. This does not work for closed curves, such as the one around region `1` in the figure above, particularly if they are not continuous (i.e. a retangle)
- Breaking the domain into buckets: initially, those buckets that contain a vtk point are filled with the region flags associated with that point; the remaining buckets are then filled based on their neighbours. The bucket in which `rp` falls then returns its set of flags. However, I am having trouble getting this to work when the bucket contains more than one region flag (i.e. when `rp` is close to a line).

I assume that this is probably a solved problem, but I am not quite sure where to look. I have thought about the [point-in-polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) problem, but I am dealing with curves rather than polygons. Other ideas involve ray tracing, but it seems like that is more suited to 3D.

Can anyone suggest an alternative, or a modification to what I have tried?

Comment: Do you know the start and end of each line?

Comment: @fraxel The lines are fully specified (start, end, region flags)

Comment: figured they must be, but I don't think we even need that :)

Answer (score 0):

Every line on the perimeter of the sub-domain of interest (SDOI) must have the SDOI as one of its bordering domains.

- So you can flood fill (or expand a circle) in the domain that `rp` is in.
- Find what is the common domain neighboured by of all these lines.
- That is you SDOI.

UNLESS:

Special case: `rp` is in a ring (ie. domain 1). So we don't know if we are inside or outside the ring. We know we are in this 'special case' because only two domains are returned from the above method (1 or 2), but we don't know which one.

Solution:

- Traverse a line from `rp` until it crosses the enclosing line, passing into another domain.
- Now do the flood fill in this domain, BUT exclude the line you cross (and all lines from the first flood fill).
- The domain neighboured all these lines is NOT your SDOI
- So you can now deduce the SDOI from the first flood fill.

Comment: you needn't flood fill, you could just keep sending out rays from `rp` until you have hit two lines that both have a different neighbouring domain. Again the SDOI is the common one. Much quicker...